# how to stop this code from hanging at wrong inputs?

Tags: c

I am learning C from ' programming in C' by Stephen Kochan. I am working on exercise no 4 of chapter 6 , writing a code that acts as a simple accumulator calculator. code is following. it works fine as long as inputs are provided in the right manner order.

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        float num, accum = 0;

        char operator;


        while(1)

        {

          printf("Enter the number and the operator ");
          scanf("%f %c",&num, &operator);

          if (operator == 'E') break;

          switch (operator){

        case 'S':
          accum = num;
          printf("= %g\n",accum);
          break;

        case '+':
          accum = accum + num;
          printf("= %g\n",accum);
          break;

        case '-':
          accum = accum - num;
          printf("= %g\n",accum);
          break;

        case '*': 
          accum = accum * num;
          printf("= %g\n",accum);
          break;

        case '/':
          accum = accum / num;
          printf("= %g\n",accum);
          break;
          }      
        }

        printf("= %g\n",accum);
        printf("End of Calculation\n");

      return 0;

    }
```

but it hangs on the wrong inputs. what can be done to check such behaviour?

Comment: `operator` is a C++ keyword. This is probably not the best choice for a variable name in C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short version is "don't use `scanf()`."

The problem is that `scanf()` provides only a limited indication of error, and leaves the erroneous data unread tp be picked up by the next call; especially if you're not bothering to do error checking, it's just going to spin forever on the bad data.

1. **Always** check the return code, so you know if it worked or not.
2. If you're doing line oriented input, use `fgets()` or similar to read an entire line, and `sscanf()` to parse from the line.
3. Do something sensible if the input isn't what you expected, instead of just barreling on through.  (Your existing code just assumes it's always valid.)

Answer (score 2):

Dont use `scanf`. Thats the first sight suggestion for this program. Use something like `getchar` like shown [here](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/languages/c/programming-bbrown/c_055.htm) They are dealing with the same problem as yours.

Comment: then how would I take input from the user?

Comment: aha.. its the scanf function that is not so foolproof as I expected.. I am yet to learn about other functions used for user input..

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `scanf()`. You just have to confirm that it scanned both arguments by testing its return value.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Even if we confirm from the return arguments of `scanf()`, its still a pain to handle the failing getchars etc etc after you enter wrong data in scanf().

Comment: @PavanManjunath: Agreed, but if you're happy to `exit(1)` on bad input, then `scanf()` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check that `scanf()` returns 2, indicating that it has populated both arguments
2. Provide a default case in the switch statement that reports an error.

For increased robustness, you might want to read the whole line using `fgets()` (don't use `gets()` because it is vulnerable to buffer overflow) and parse the result using `sscanf()`. This is only necessary if you want to provide recovery from bad inputs. Otherwise, just stick with `scanf()` and `exit(1)` (and an error message) if anything goes wrong.